# Identifier not found even though it's there?

Tags: c++

When trying to compile in VS19 I keep getting the error of

> 'isReserved': identifier not found>

Im not too sure where to go because isReserved is declared as a boolean function in the exact same file.

#### Error Segment

```
ScannerForIdents aScanner(inFile);
    int nextToken;
    while((nextToken = aScanner.getIdent()) == 1) {
        lexeme = aScanner.getLastLexeme();
        if (!isReserved(lexeme)) {
            currentLineNumber = aScanner.getNumberOfLines();
            xRefTable[lexeme].insert(currentLineNumber);
        }
    }
```

#### isReserved

```
bool isReserved(string lexeme) {
    static const unsigned NUM_RESERVED = 74;
    static string reservedWord[NUM_RESERVED] = //Reserved Words
    //const vector<string> reservedWord
    {   
        "and", "and_eq", "asm", "auto", "bitand" // Other words that I didn't include here
    };
    for (const auto& reservedWord : reservedWord) {
        if (reservedWord == lexeme) {
            return true;    // Returns true if reservedWord matches lexeme
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

Comment: Is the `isReserved` declared before or after `aScanner`?

Comment: I am so mad at myself, thank you for that amazing answer!

Comment: Not a problem.  :-)  The declaration/definition order — rather than a holistic view like some other languages have — is something everyone who uses C++ has to learn.  And often relearn until it's ingrained.

Comment: Thank you! Its a hard thing to get used to but I love it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you posted `aScanner` before `isReserved` perhaps you need to declare it beforehand

Please note that you can forward-declare a function without implementing it:

```cpp
bool isReserved(string lexeme);
```

at the top of the file, or in your header file.